# Laravel PATCH works on update but validation in controller fails

Tags: laravel, validation, controller, put

I am following along with the Laracast lab, the Tweety feed and all was going good until i hit a wall.

I have a PATCH to update the user profile and it works and updates the record, but the validation doesn't. The form submits if fully complete and the record is fine but if the form validation fails server side in my controller, I get as below:

***Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.***

I have looked at the FAQ section here and scoured the net already asked and tried several steps to sort this. I have tried:

1. Using $user->username in my edit file template and controller.
2. Changing the route from PATCH TO PUT (and also POST, simply using store)
3. Checking the User model and ensuring I am using 'getRouteKeyName' working correctly, it is.
4. Checking if there is a conflict in the route, there is none and the order/VERB is fine.

Can anyone please help? Below is my code.

**Routes as below:**

```
// Snippet for seeing all the database queries. 
//DB::listen(function($query){var_dump($query->sql, $query->bindings);});

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

 // Home view, no sign-in required. 
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

// These routes require and use auth middleware.   
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){

// TWeets main page.
Route::get('/tweets/', 'TweetsController@index')->name('home');
// Store a new tweet
Route::post('/tweets/', 'TweetsController@store');

// Profile area, view and update

// Use the 'name' attribute in route/model binding instead of the primary key = user:name 
Route::get('/profile/{user:username}/', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile');

// Show form to edit the profile
Route::post('/profile/{user:username}/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('edit_profile');
//->middleware('can:edit,user'); // Don't forget the wildcard.

// Finally, update the users profile information.   
Route::patch('/profile/{user:username}','ProfileController@update')->name('update_profile');

// Handles the follow/unfollow on a toggle method.
Route::post('/profile/{user:username}/follow/','FollowsController@store');

// Logs you out & directs to the homepage.
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

});

Auth::routes();
```

**Controller as below:**

```
 /**
 * Update the users profile after validation
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(User $user)
{
        $validated = request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'username'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
            'password_confirmation'=>'required',
        ]);

         $user->update($validated);

    // Redirect to the tweets page which is called 'home'.
    return redirect(route('profile', $user->username));
}
```

**Template:**

```
<x-app>

<form class="w-full" method="POST" action="{{route('update_profile',$user)}}">

    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf


    <h2 class="text-xl mb-2 py-4 font-bold">Edit profile for {{$user->username}}</h2> 
    <p class="text-sm mb-5 mt-0">Below you an update your profile details.</p>

    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">

        <div class="w-full px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-name">Name</label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Mike Smith.." name="name" value="{{$user->name}}"/>
        </div>

        @error('name')
            <p>{{$message}}</p>
        @enderror

        <div class="w-full px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-username">Username</label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-username" type="text" placeholder="MikeSmith1..." name="username" value="{{$user->username}}"/>
        </div>

        @error('username')
            <p>{{$message}}</p>
        @enderror

        <div class="w-full px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-username">Email</label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-username" type="email" placeholder="MikeSmith@yahoo.com..." name="email" value="{{$user->email}}"/>
        </div>

        @error('email')
            <p>{{$message}}</p>
        @enderror


        <div class="w-full px-3">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-password">Password</label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-password" type="password" name="password"/>

            <p class="mb-3 text-red-600 text-xs italic">Make it as long and as crazy as you'd like</p>
        </div>

        <div class="w-full px-3"> {{-- This HAS to be called "password_confirmation" --}}
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-password">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-password_confirmation" type="password" name="password_confirmation"/>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 ml-2 mt-4 px-4 rounded">
            Update details
        </button> 

    </div>
</form>
</x-app>
```

**Model:User**

```
 /**
 * Laravel <=6 - use this method, after v6, you can do this on the route itself. 
 * Using this so we can use a user name in the route, instead of the ID Laravel normally uses for route/model binding. Now you can use /profile/mikethornley 
 * This will still enable route/model binding to work and still find the user
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: try to `dd($errors)` in blade instead of `<p>{{$message}}</p>` and see what you get

Comment: That's not really the issue i have. The issue is the partially submitted form throwing this: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. I think past that, the errors would be visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
// Use the 'name' attribute in route/model binding instead of the primary key = user:name 
Route::get('/profile/{user:username}/', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile');

// Finally, update the users profile information.   
Route::patch('/profile/{user:username}','ProfileController@update')->name('update_profile');
```

Your routes are clashing... that post ends up in the show() method and that's why you get the error.

You need to make some change in that post route if you want to have parameters. For example

```
Route::patch('/profile-update/{user:username}','ProfileController@update')->name('update_profile');
```

Comment: That odd considering the verbs are different and just tried it and it failed. I also never saws it hit show. I've also just cleared the cache.

Comment: @lewis4u No, then every resource route will have this behavior :-)

Comment: The form submits, if completed, as it did originally... the issue is the GET error. Both of those routes use different VERBS and so should be fine. I expected to be directed back to the update form and the errors show.

Comment: @MikeThornley can you please make dd('show') inside your show() method in controller and leave the routes as they are. Then you should not get this error: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route.`

Comment: Done and i got::"show" which is expected at that renders the profile.

Comment: If i take out the validation, the form submits which suggests everything is fine but the controller validation is causing the issue.

Comment: OK I wasn't clear enough... you need to leave all as it is in this question... put `dd("string");` on the first line inside the show() method... and then submit the form.

Comment: Yeah but what I mean is show is rendering the profile and is nothing to do with the submission. When I submit the form, I am certain I hot update, without question.

Comment: dump and die inside show, would not render the profile as that is beforehand.

Comment: if you have time I would really like to see this remotely via team viewer or something

Comment: Sure, that'd be great