# Laravel PATCH validation fails in controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation, controller, patch

My problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214626/laravel-patch-works-on-update-but-validation-in-controller-fails) the different is I'm using modal to display the update fields. When I doing a `PATCH` request to my controller, my validation is failed on the `required` rules. I'm copying on how `Laravel Breeze` `UpdateProfileInformation` way to pass an form to new customized request and then proceed validate the rules there, if the validation works then it will dump the data.

But its always said `"The xx field is required"` although the `request` is already passed and filled with previous data
Here is the codes :

**Update.vue**

```
<template>
    <div @click.self="closeModal()" class="backdrop">
        <div
            class="bg-base-100 justify-center items-center text-center w-[90%] h-fit p-5 m-auto mt-[3%] mb-[2%] overflow-auto rounded-md"
        >
            <slot class="w-fit h-fit">
                <div class="p-2 flex flex-col">
                    <div
                        class="font-semibold text-xl text-neutral-content leading-tight mb-5"
                    >
                        <h1>Update existing data</h1>
                    </div>
                    <form @submit.prevent="update">
                        <div
                            class="p-2 flex flex-row card bg-neutral rounded-md"
                        >
                            <div class="w-[50%] items-center p-2">
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <div>
                                        <div v-if="tempUrl" class="p-5">
                                            <!-- M̶a̶k̶e̶s̶ C̶h̶e̶c̶k̶,̶ i̶f̶ o̶p̶e̶n̶ f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ t̶i̶m̶e̶,̶ t̶a̶k̶e̶ i̶m̶g̶ u̶r̶l̶ f̶r̶o̶m̶ d̶b̶ a̶n̶d̶ d̶i̶s̶p̶l̶a̶y̶ i̶t̶ -->
                                            <!-- I̶f̶ t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ i̶s̶ a̶ c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ i̶n̶ i̶m̶a̶g̶e̶,̶ c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ p̶r̶e̶v̶i̶e̶w̶ t̶o̶ c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ i̶m̶a̶g̶e̶ -->
                                            <h2 class="m-2">Preview Image</h2>
                                            <img
                                                class="m-auto rounded-md border-2 border-primary p-2"
                                                :src="tempUrl"
                                                alt=""
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div v-else>
                                            <!-- Change to img later -->
                                            <h1>{{ form.image }}</h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                                        <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Image</h1>
                                        <input
                                            id="image"
                                            @change="setImage"
                                            type="file"
                                            class="file-input file-input-sm rounded-md file-input-bordered file-input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                        />
                                        <InputError
                                            class="mt-2"
                                            :message="form.errors.image"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <div>
                                        <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Code</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex flex-row">
                                        <div v-if="radioCode">
                                            <TextInput
                                                id="codeText"
                                                v-model="form.code"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                                required
                                            />
                                            <InputError
                                                class="mt-2"
                                                :message="form.errors.code"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div v-else>
                                            <select
                                                id="codeSelect"
                                                v-model="form.code"
                                                class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                                required
                                            >
                                                <option disabled selected>
                                                    Existing Code
                                                </option>
                                                <option
                                                    v-for="furniture in Furnitures"
                                                >
                                                    {{ furniture.code }}
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                            <InputError
                                                class="mt-2"
                                                :message="form.errors.code"
                                            />
                                            <!-- Radio Group -->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ml-5 flex flex-col">
                                            <div class="flex flex-row">
                                                <input
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    name="radioCode"
                                                    class="mb-2 radio radio-sm radio-primary bg-inherit enabled:hover:border-info enabled:checked:bg-primary"
                                                    value="new"
                                                    @change="onChange($event)"
                                                    checked
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio" class="ml-2"
                                                    >New data</label
                                                >
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="flex flex-row">
                                                <input
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    name="radioCode"
                                                    class="radio radio-sm radio-primary bg-inherit enabled:hover:border-info enabled:checked:bg-primary"
                                                    value="exist"
                                                    @change="onChange($event)"
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio" class="ml-2"
                                                    >Existing data</label
                                                >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Description</h1>
                                    <TextInput
                                        id="description"
                                        v-model="form.description"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.description"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Category</h1>
                                    <select
                                        id="category"
                                        v-model="form.category"
                                        @change="categoryChange"
                                        class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    >
                                        <option v-for="category in categories">
                                            {{ category }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.category"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Wood Type</h1>
                                    <select
                                        id="woodtype"
                                        v-model="form.woodtype"
                                        class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    >
                                        <option v-if="isRoot" value="Root">
                                            Root
                                        </option>
                                        <option
                                            v-if="!isRoot"
                                            v-for="notRoot in notRootType"
                                        >
                                            {{ notRoot }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.woodtype"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-[50%] items-center p-2">
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Width</h1>
                                    <NumberInput
                                        id="width"
                                        v-model="form.width"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.width"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Depth</h1>
                                    <NumberInput
                                        id="depth"
                                        v-model="form.depth"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.depth"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Height</h1>
                                    <NumberInput
                                        id="height"
                                        v-model="form.height"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.height"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Stock</h1>
                                    <NumberInput
                                        id="stock"
                                        v-model="form.stock"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.stock"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col p-2">
                                    <h1 class="m-2 text-start">Price</h1>
                                    <NumberInput
                                        id="price"
                                        v-model="form.price"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="Type here"
                                        class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                    />
                                    <InputError
                                        class="mt-2"
                                        :message="form.errors.price"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button
                                class="btn m-4 px-10 btn-info"
                                :disabled="form.processing"
                            >
                                <div v-if="form.processing">
                                    <span
                                        class="loading loading-spinner loading-sm text-primary"
                                        >Update</span
                                    >
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>
                                    <span>Update</span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput.vue";
import NumberInput from "@/Components/NumberInput.vue";
import InputLabel from "@/Components/InputLabel.vue";
import { Link, useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { ref } from "vue";
import InputError from "@/Components/InputError.vue";
export default {
    props: ["SelectedFurniture", "Furnitures"],
    components: {
        AuthenticatedLayout,
        PrimaryButton,
        TextInput,
        NumberInput,
        InputLabel,
        InputError,
    },
    setup(props) {
        const radioCode = ref(true);
        const categories = ["Indoor", "Outdoor", "Handicraft", "Root"];
        const notRootType = ["Teak wood", "Tiger wood", "Mahogany wood"];
        const isRoot = ref(false);
        const selectedCategory = ref("");
        let tempUrl = ref("");

        const form = useForm({
            uuid: props.SelectedFurniture.uuid,
            image: props.SelectedFurniture.image,
            code: props.SelectedFurniture.code,
            description: props.SelectedFurniture.description,
            category: props.SelectedFurniture.category,
            woodtype: props.SelectedFurniture.wood_type,
            width: parseInt(props.SelectedFurniture.width),
            depth: parseInt(props.SelectedFurniture.width),
            height: parseInt(props.SelectedFurniture.height),
            stock: parseInt(props.SelectedFurniture.stock),
            price: parseFloat(props.SelectedFurniture.price),
        });
        console.log(props.SelectedFurniture.wood_type);

        const update = () => {
            // console.log(form);
            form.patch(route("input.update"));
        };

        return {
            form,
            radioCode,
            categories,
            notRootType,
            isRoot,
            selectedCategory,
            tempUrl,
            update,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        closeModal() {
            this.$emit("close");
        },
        setImage(event) {
            const file = event.target.files;
            this.form.image = file[0];
            this.tempUrl = URL.createObjectURL(this.form.image);
            // console.log(this.tempUrl);
        },
        onChange(event) {
            this.radioCode = !this.radioCode;
            this.form.reset("code");
            // console.log(this.radioCode);
            // console.log(this.form);
        },
        categoryChange(event) {
            if (event.target.options.selectedIndex > -1) {
                this.selectedCategory = event.target.value;
                if (this.selectedCategory == "Root") {
                    this.isRoot = true;
                } else {
                    this.isRoot = false;
                }
                // console.log(this.isRoot);
                // console.log(this.selectedCategory);
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.modal {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.backdrop {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**InputController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\InputUpdateRequest;

class InputController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();

        // dd($user);
        $furniture = DB::table('furniture')
        ->get();
        // dd($furniture);



    return Inertia::render('Input/Input', [
        'furnitures' => $furniture,
    ]);

    }

    public function create(Request $request){
        $validationInteger = "required|integer";
        $validationString = "required|string";
        $request -> validate([
            'image' => "required|file",
            'description' => $validationString,
            'category' => $validationString,
            'woodtype' => $validationString,
            'width' => $validationInteger,
            'height' => $validationInteger,
            'depth' => $validationInteger,
            'stock' => $validationInteger,
            'price' => $validationInteger,
        ]);

        // sleep(30);

        dd($request->all());
    }

    public function update(InputUpdateRequest $request){


            dd($request->all());



    }
}
```

**InputUpdateRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class InputUpdateRequest extends FormRequest{

    public function rules(): array{
        $validationInteger = ["required","integer"];
        $validationString = ["required","string"];
        return [
            'uuid' => $validationString,
            'image' => ["required","file"],
            'description' => $validationString,
            'category' => $validationString,
            'woodtype' => $validationString,
            'width' => $validationInteger,
            'height' => $validationInteger,
            'depth' => $validationInteger,
            'stock' => $validationInteger,
            'price' => $validationInteger,
            ];
        }
}
```

**Routers**

```
Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/input',[InputController::class, 'index'])->name('input.index');
    Route::post('/input',[InputController::class, 'create'])->name('input.create');
    Route::patch('/input',[InputController::class, 'update'])->name('input.update');
    Route::delete('/input',[InputController::class, 'delete'])->name('input.delete');

});
```

I tried using `sometimes` rule, but it will causing endless loading,

When I dump the request normally, it's passing the data succesfully
[image]

**Edit :**

I tried do the validation straight from the function itself still not working, but when I dump it, the requests is passed successfully

```
    public function update(Request $request){

        // dd($request->all());
        $validationInteger = "required|integer";
        $validationString = "required|string";
        $request -> validate([
            'image' => "required|file",
            'description' => $validationString,
            'category' => $validationString,
            'woodtype' => $validationString,
            'width' => $validationInteger,
            'height' => $validationInteger,
            'depth' => $validationInteger,
            'stock' => $validationInteger,
            'price' => $validationInteger,
            ]);
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's network inspector to see what values are being submitted? Or try dumping the values from the FormRequest class? Exactly what fields are causing a problem, since you don't appear to have an "xx" field in your form?

Comment: I tried to do the validation from the update function instead (not using `InputUpdateRequest` ) still the same

Comment: as you can see in the edited post, I'm doing it that way still fails the validation, do I do the validation wrong ?

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't told us which fields are failing the "required" validation, a question I raised above.

Comment: all of them is failing the required validation

Comment: Ahh I found the problem, so when the image is changed , the form is reseted to "" so that causes the validation failing on the required rules, when I leave the image upload alone it worked as intended, is it because of the image preview that messes with the form content ?